# Fastest way to compare a row in Mysql to see which values are not exist in the other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables, one 3 Million rows and other 200,000 rows, I want to check if all the values in an specific row of the smaller one exist in the bigger one, if not then I want to mark them so I can recognize them and do some work on them.

So far tried,

1) `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_bigger WHERE some_condition in table_smaller)`;

2) `$something = SELECT somthing FROM 'table_smaller'`

and then check if `$something` is exist in the  bigger table using "`select count(*) from bigger_table where something="$something";` in PHP

Both methods takes at lest 1 day to finish, and I need to compare tables like this, and it makes
me wait to get the result and start to work again, I was wonder what is the best way and fastest way to compare like this.

Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to compare the tables directly, but doing this is going to cause a full table scan of both tables. Make sure that you have indexes on the specific columns that you are going to compare to minimize the time spent on scanning the tables.

The query below will contain the rows that are not present. (Cache this in Redis perhaps?)
Do the processing necessary in PHP and then construct a query/procedure for your needs based upon the results.

**Retrieve rows from table_large that do not have values matching table_small**

```
SELECT field_large FROM table_large WHERE field_large NOT IN (SELECT field_small FROM table_small)
```

The resulting values will be 2 and 3.

**Example table structure for above example**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_large` (
    `field_large` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`field_large`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_small` (
    `field_small` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`field_small`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `table_large` (`field_large`) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO `table_small` (`field_small`) VALUES (1);
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I am going to try this one right now and see how fast is it. Can you please advise me to how index my tables corectly, i am using MyISAM db, is it a good db type for a large scale database?

Comment: Try to add indexes on the fields that you perform search-operations on, what type of index you should use depends on the column type etc. I suggest you read up on the link provided below and look around the net on guides on WHEN and HOW to use indexes to speed up operations. I hope my answer to your question above with the example query helped!

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html